# Play Framework : Get session using session id

Tags: java, session, playframework, session-cookies

I am using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to handle mutli-file uploads in my Play app and I am trying to work out the best way to associate a user with an upload.

Within uploadify, you are able to assign [script data](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/) which are key value pairs passed as parameters to the server. So my idea, on the most basic level, is that I would like to pass the `id` of the users current `session` back to the upload method and then use the `session id` to get the `session`.

***My question is:** does anybody know how to get a session using the session id?*

I understand that this is not the most secure way of doing this and I will be adding a few more complications along the way. However, if someone knows, or can think of, a better away to achive what I am trying to do then I welcome their input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to understand is that the session is not a server side store. It is a cookie.

Therefore, if Uploadify passes the cookie data up with the http headers, then you can access the session using the normal way you access a cookie from your controller. This gets over your security concerns.

If the cookie is not passed across, then you will have to find a neater way to pass information across. You could do something simple by encoding your userid in your controller and passing this as script data.